# Где выходит массив за границу?

Tags: массивы, java

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
        if (list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(i)) > 0) {
            String tmp = list.get(i);
            list.remove(i);
            list.add(i, list.get(j));
            list.remove(j);
            list.add(j, tmp);
        }
    } 
}
```

> Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index: 3, Size: 3     at
> java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown
> Source)   at Task1.main(Task1.java:30)

Comment: Попробуйте `Collections.sort(list)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вообще, ответ на ваш вопрос содержится в приведённом вами же стэктрэйсе:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) at Task1.main(**Task1.java:30**)

Судя по всему, исключение возникает на строке

```
list.add(i, list.get(j));
```

где вы пытаетесь получить j-й элемент коллекции, не учитывая при этом, что предыдущей строкой, а именно:

```
list.remove(i);
```

вы уменьшили количество элементов в нём.

Answer (score 2):

```
at Task1.main(Task1.java:30)
```

В классе *Task1* методе *main()* строчке *30*

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы просто не делать вот так:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
           for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(i)) > 0) {
                String tmp = list.get(i);
                list.add(i, list.get(j));
                list.add(j, tmp);
            }
        } 
    }
```

Код будет выполнять тоже самое, только исключения того не будет.

Comment: Правда, что-то мне подсказывает, что циклиться будет...)
Вообщем, если что, дебаг Вам в помощь

Comment: Насколько я понимаю если добавить в ArrayList Элемент на 0 индекс, то все элементы листа сместятся вправо, а длина увеличиться на один.